# react-router transition animation on initial page load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I would like to apply animations to components when I transition with [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), and I am able to do this only after the initial load, however I want to see the animation on the initial mount as well (page refresh).

This is what I have tried. Note `transitionAppear: true` did not do anything:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();
    }

    render() {

        let path = this.context.router.getCurrentPath();
        path = path.substring(0, path.split('/', 2).join('/').length);
        return (
            Transitions({component: 'div', transitionName: 'fade', transitionAppear: true},
                handler({key: path})
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading client side only or server side too?

Comment: For now it is just client side. This shouldn't make a difference though?

Comment: I'm doing some transitions, and if the page is loaded server side it never fires the appear event. Have you inspected the generated DOM to see if the classes are being added?

Comment: As far as I can see, no classes are being changed on initial load. After that as soon as I change the component rendered in the RouteHandler - animations work as expected

Comment: When I used animations with initial mounting, I wasn't mounting in the correct order. I'm not familiar with your class structure, but maybe this might help. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animation-group-must-be-mounted-to-work.

Comment: Oh - I did read the docs but I guess I did not read them propperly. I assumed that the `transitionAppear` triggers the `enter` css class. I created an `appear` class and animations performed as expected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a re-reading of [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animation-group-must-be-mounted-to-work) I realised that `transitionAppear` triggers its own css class (`.appear`). Adding this class fixed my problem.